# boundedness of a sequence $ \in L^{\infty}(I,H^1(M))\cap Lip(I,L^2(M))$ implies that its temporal derivative is bounded as well

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, hyperbolic-pde

Hi I have the next claim which I would like to find a proof of it.

I have a sequence of functions $u_\epsilon(t,x) \in H^1(M)$ where $M$ is a compact manifold, and $u_\epsilon \in L^\infty(I,H^1(M))\cap Lip(I,L^2(M))$ where $I$ is some interval that includes zero in it.

The claim is that $\partial_t u_\epsilon$ is bounded in $L^\infty(I,L^2(M))$, why is that necessarily true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because that is the same as Lip.

Comment: Can you elaborate, I am not sure I follow. BTW, I edited and changed $L^2(M)$ to $H^1(M)$ in the space $L^\infty(I,L^2(M))\cap Lip(I,L^2(M))$.